# Build fail in xcode

Tags: react-native

This error is returned after building my react native project in xcode.

[image: Error returned after build]

But if i run **npx react-native run-ios** in the IDE build is successful but the error below is thrown in the terminal when trying to build bundle.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I went into the package.json file for the react-native-info module and deleted    "react-native": "index.ts"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).